# Roadmap for tod_detecting?

Tags: ros, object-recognition, tod-detecting, tod-training

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's on the roadmap for tod_detecting such that I can see what I can expect in future revisions of tod_detecting? I'd be happy to have a rough frame about the bigger changes and improvements that are certainly to come, given the recent activity on this package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9583/roadmap-for-tod_detecting?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tod_detecting is meant to go away in favor of a simpler and more generic object recognition ROS API: give me data and I'll tell you what's in there.

It will share components with TOD but also with our other object recognition pipelines.

Timeline: always easy to give one but harder to stick to it :) We are working on getting all that ready by the end of August.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1